# Emacs triple click handler

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, keymap

What handler is called when I make triple click ? For me, it select whole line. I want this behavior to be binded to C-l, how to do it ?

EDIT:

I tried to bind this to key, but not works, how to fix it?

```
(defun custom/mark-whole-line  ()
   (interactive)
   (mouse-start-end 0 (buffer-size) 2))
```

Comment: The answer to your edit is not so simple. That's why I ran through all of the code I mentioned. The `mouse.el` code is a bit convoluted, in part because the Emacs mouse does a lot of different things with the same buttons. If you want a command that does only what triple-clicking `mouse-1` does then you (or someone else) will need to dig into that code and compose bits of it (or similar or write code from scratch) to do the job.

Comment: In any case, to bind a mouse event to a command you typically need for the command to use `"e"` in the `interactive` spec. Check the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean the key-binding `<triple-mouse-1>`.

You can sort-of answer your question by using `C-h k` followed by triple-clicking `mouse-1` (the first/left mouse button).

This is what I see when I do that in the Emacs 26 pretest:

> `<mouse-1>` (translated from `<triple-mouse-1>`) at that spot runs the
>   command `mouse-set-point` (found in `global-map`), which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `mouse.el`.
>
> It is bound to `mouse-1`.
>
> `(mouse-set-point EVENT &optional PROMOTE-TO-REGION)`
>
> Move point to the position clicked on with the mouse.
>
> This should be bound to a mouse click event type.
>
> If `PROMOTE-TO-REGION` is non-`nil` and event is a multiple-click, select
>   the corresponding element around point, with the resulting position of
>   point determined by `mouse-select-region-move-to-beginning`.

In Emacs prior to Emacs 26 you also see the doc for the button-down event, `<down-mouse-1>`.

To figure out what's happening you need to check the code of `mouse-set-point`. You'll see that when called interactively its second arg, `PROMOTE-TO-REGION`, is non-`nil` (coming from the numeric prefix arg).  So it calls `mouse-set-region`.

Function `mouse-set-region` then calls `mouse-start-end`, passing `(1- click-count)`, where `click-count` is the number of clicks. For a triple-click it thus passes `2`.

Finally, given the value `2` as its `MODE` argument, function `mouse-start-end` selects the whole line.  Its doc string (`C-h f mouse-start-end`) tells you:

> **`mouse-start-end`** is a compiled Lisp function in `mouse.el`.
>
> `(mouse-start-end START END MODE)`
>
> Return a list of region bounds based on `START` and `END` according to `MODE`.
>
> If `MODE` is 0 then set point to `(min START END)`, mark to `(max START END)`.
>
> If `MODE` is 1 then set point to start of word at `(min START END)`,
>   mark to end of word at `(max START END)`.
>
> **If `MODE` is 2 then do the same for lines.**

Whew!  Not so easy, but Emacs finally tells you what you wanted to know. It is (ultimately) function `mouse-start-end` that selects the whole line. But it does that only because of the `MODE` parameter passed to it from `mouse-set-region`.  And `mouse-set-region` only does the right thing because of code that is in `mouse-set-point`.

Comment: Thank you, I have little second question (more in EDIT).